# Notation: gradient as vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, tangent-bundle

Consider the tangent space $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose $\{\big(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}\big)_p\}$ is a basis. So my textbook says that the gradient of a function $f$, $f\in C^\infty(U)$, $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with $U$ open, is defined to be: $$\text{grad}(f):=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$ but I am failing to see why it would not be $$:=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$$
so that evaluated at $p\in U$, we get the gradient vector at $p$. 
In other words, how is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ a vector field? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your interpretation. Given the conventions I am familiar with, 
$$ \nabla f=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.$$
In this way, $\nabla f$ lives in the tangent  bundle. The expression 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p\in \mathbb{R}$$
which is probably not what we want our gradient to be.

Comment: $\nabla\cdot\nabla f$ is a sum of second partial derivatives, not a sum of first partial derivatives.

Comment: Sorry you're totally right, not sure why I wrote  that :-) Wasn't relevant anyways.